# Word Macro - Log changes made by a find and replace

Tags: vba, ms-word, full-text-search

I have the below code that will search through a word document replacing any IDs it finds with a masked version of the number using RegEx (e.g. 412345678900 becomes 4123####8900). Each document could have multiple IDs in it. The IDs are sometimes scattered throughout the document text and not just in tables (so Excel is not an option).

I want to be able to write each of the replaced versions of the text found out to a log file with the file path and file name.

```
Sub Auto_Masking()

'Start at the very beginning. It's a very good place to start.
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    With Selection.Find  ' Locate and mask the 12 digit IDs
        .Text = "<([4][0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})>"
        .Replacement.Text = "\1####\3"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

'Put the user back at the beginning of the document
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
End Sub
```

How can I write/append each now masked number to a log file?  I would like to have the log file show a list of all the IDs masked and the file they were in, so each line in the log file should look something like this:

filePath\fileName ; maskedID

with a line for each ID number masked (with one file potentially containing multiple IDs). e.g.:

```
c:\temp\test.docx;4123####8900
c:\temp\test.docx;4241####7629
c:\location\another.docx;4379####8478
```

I have a horrible feeling this is going to be impossible based on trying to get the value I want in the log file to display in a msgbox. After days of experimenting, I'm completely out of ideas.

I'm thinking a find and a find/replace may have to be used in a larger loop, one to do the replace, and one to find what was just replaced before moving on. Maybe based on Selection.Find.Found = True

- Selection.Find.Text will display the regex
- Selection.Text will display only the first character of the ID number string, but no more
- Selection.Find.Replacement.Text will display the string as it appears in the With section, without replacing the /1 and /3 with the values it found

Comment: Are you limited to using Word for this?  Excel seems to be a much better choice given you are working with records.  This exercise would be so much simpler in Excel.

Comment: Hi Joehanna, yes, it needs to work in Word. I already have this working in Excel, however Excel doesn't seem to like playing with the .doc and .docx formats in our locked down SOE.

Comment: I should add, I have it working in Excel for default Excel file types.  I need this working in Word for default Word file types. Our SOE is very locked down in that regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 10 minutes after giving up, I worked it out.

The code to solve the issue and successfully complete the above task, with logging of each masked ID, is as follows:

```
Sub mask_card_numbers()
'
   Dim Counter As Long

' This next section prepares for log writing
    Dim Log1 As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    ' ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
    Set LogIDs = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\LogDIR\IDs_Masked_with_Word.txt", 8, True)

' Get the filename and path for the log file
    FileName = ActiveDocument.Path & "\" & ActiveDocument.Name


' Mask IDs ####################################################
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
' The first pass collects a single digit from the text to search for which would artificially increase the counter so reduce it by one in advance
    Counter = Counter - 1 
    Do
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "<([4][0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})>"
            .Replacement.Text = "\1xxxxxxxx\3"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End With
' By keeping the selected text after the replacement, the masked
        FoundID = Selection.Text

' Write masked ID to a logfile
        If Len(FoundID) > 7 Then  ' Anything greater than 1 will probably work
            LogIDs.WriteLine FileName & ";" & FoundID 
        End If
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne
    Loop While Selection.Find.Found <> False

' Done Masking IDs ###########################################

End Sub
```

Comment: I stumble upon your macro while searching for something else, and it's a good little macro.
I'd add `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` in the beginning and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at the end, to prevent flickering while MS-Word is running the macro

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you can do this with Word's Find & Replace if you want to intercept the values to log them to a file.

I suggest using the `Find` and iterating through them to manually mask the numbers and write them to a log file. I also tweaked your `regex` as it didn't work.  The code below only works on one file at a time.

```
Sub Auto_Masking()

  Dim oDoc As Document
  Dim oSelection As Range
  Dim cc As String
  Dim bFound As Boolean


  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  'Handle to the relevant document
  Set oDoc = ActiveDocument

  'Handle to the whole doc's text
  Set oSelection = oDoc.Content

  'Create your log file. Amend this to cope with Append if needed
  Open "C:\Temp\ChangeLog.txt" For Output As #1

  With oSelection.Find
    .Text = "<([4])([0-9]{15})>"  'NOTE: this will only work for Visa cards
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchWildcards = True

    bFound = True

    While bFound

      'Look for the next occurrence
      bFound = .Execute

      If bFound Then
        'Raw text
        cc = oSelection.Text

        'Manually scramble it
        oSelection.Text = Left(cc, 4) & "xxxx" & Right(cc, 4)

        Print #1, oDoc.FullName & ";" & oSelection.Text

        '*** Remove for Production ***
        'Show the result in the Immediate window whilst debugging.
        Debug.Print cc & " => " & oSelection.Text

      End If

    Wend

  End With

  'Close the log file
  Close #1

  'Be a good memory citizen
  Set oSelection = Nothing
  Set oDoc = Nothing

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure, my code above works for me so long as the dir for the log file exists.  That said, I did change the question to a context of 12 digit IDs to remove any fear factor about dealing with credit cards (16 digit).
To make my correct code above work 
set the following two lines in the With Selection.Find:
  .Text = "<([4][0-9]{3})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})([0-9]{4})>"  
  .Replacement.Text = "\1xxxxxxxx\4"

Comment: johanna, your code does indeed work, I hadn't tested it because you solved it around the same time as I solved it myself. Your code would need a minor modification not to overwrite the changelog file if the macro is run on multiple documents on the same machine. Stackoverflow won't allow me to mark both as the solution.